# Receiving events from OPC UA server using QOpcUaClient

Tags: qt, opc-ua

I'm trying to receive Events coming from OPC UA Server using QOpcUaClient. I see in UA Expert that the node is sending events, but I just cannot connect the client to them in my code

Here is my code

```
    QOpcUaClient *mOpcUaClient = nullptr;
    QScopedPointer<QOpcUaNode> m_eventNode;

...

    m_eventNode.reset(mOpcUaClient->node("ns=2;s=testObject"));
    QOpcUaMonitoringParameters monitoringParams(1000);

    QOpcUaMonitoringParameters::EventFilter filter;
    filter << QOpcUaSimpleAttributeOperand("Message"); // Select clause of the filter

    QOpcUaContentFilterElement condition;
    condition << QOpcUaContentFilterElement::FilterOperator::GreaterThanOrEqual;
    condition << QOpcUaSimpleAttributeOperand("Severity");
    condition << QOpcUaLiteralOperand(10, QOpcUa::Types::UInt16);
    filter << condition; // Where clause of the filter

    monitoringParams.setFilter(filter);
    monitoringParams.setIndexRange("0:20");

    m_eventNode->enableMonitoring(QOpcUa::NodeAttribute::EventNotifier, monitoringParams);

    QObject::connect(m_eventNode.data(), &QOpcUaNode::eventOccurred, []()
    {
        qDebug() << "OPC UA Event occurred";
    });
```

I expect that with this code, I would get text "OPC UA Event occured" to the app output every time a certain type of event is received from "testObject" node

Calling the "enableMonitoring()" gives:
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541: Could not add monitored item for QOpcUa::NodeAttribute::EventNotifier of node "ns=2;s=testObject" : BadInternalError

The client is working fine otherwise. I'm able to read, write and subsribe values without problems.

Is there anyone who could help me with this?

Also, I would be happy to hear, if anyone could explain what the index range means and what value I should set there on line "monitoringParams.setIndexRange("0:20");" as it might be part of the solution

I'm using Windows 10, Qt 5.15.2, MinGW 64 bit, Qt creator 9.0.2, open62541 plugin for OPC UA

Answer (score 0):

The index range should not be needed in our example. It's used to accessed arrays when you subscripe to a variable.

Comment: Ok, that is good to know, thanks! But if I comment out that line, I get "BadIndexRangeInvalid". I believe, an empty index range is not accepted. Do you know what should I set as an index range in this case? I have tried different ranges and single numbers with no luck